# Find value using multiple criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got a table with columns, each containing customer contact information. I've also got a formula that finds a phone number using multiple criteria: `customer ID`, `type` (mobile, home etc), and `primary` Y/N. The problem is this information can occur several times but with a different date, in which case the newest occurrence needs to be selected. The current CSE formula is:

```
=INDEX($C$6:$BZ$18;10;MATCH(<client_ID>;IF(($C$8:$BZ$8=<client_ID>)*($C$17:$BZ$17="home")*($C$18:$BZ$18="Y");$C$8:$BZ$8);0))
```

where
 $C$6:$BZ$18 contains all data
 $C$8:$BZ$8 contains all client IDs
 $C$17:$BZ$17 contains the types of phone numbers
 $C$18:$BZ$18 contains whether this number is the primary number of that type
 $C$8:$BZ$8 contains the date a number was entered

The data looks like this:

```
   B              C           D
---------------------------------------------------------------------
8  CLIENTID     |Client1    |Client1    |
9  other        |           |           |
10 other        |           |           |
11 other        |           |           |
12 other        |           |           |
13 other        |           |           |
14 other        |           |           |
15 PHONE NUMBER |9876543210 |1234567890 |
16 DATE         |2015-04-15 |2015-04-16 |
17 TYPE         |Home       |Home       |
18 Primary      |Y          |Y          |
```

The above formula selects phone number `9876543210` but it needs to select `1234567890` because that is the latest entry.

Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

Comment: please provide a screenshot of your data; an image or link to an image, so that we can see. and provide the expected result as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The underlying value of dates are numbers so we can look for the furthest date to the right in a row by searching for an impossibly high number with the [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca) without looking for an exact match.

[image: Last number in row]

The *array formula* in F6 is,

```
=INDEX($B$8:$BZ$18, MATCH(F$5, $B$8:$B$18, 0), MATCH(1E+99, IF($B$8:$BZ$8=$C6, IF($B$17:$BZ$17=$D6, IF($B$18:$BZ$18=$E6, $B$16:$BZ$16)))))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

If your dates are in ascending order (left-to-right) then an exact match will have to be sought. A three criteria pseudo-MAXIF formula can return that into the original formula modified to look for an exact match. If the maximum date is duplicated, the first one is returned.

```
=INDEX($C$8:$BZ$18, MATCH(F$5, $B$8:$B$18, 0), MATCH(MAX(INDEX($C$16:$BZ$16*($C$8:$BZ$8=$C6)*($C$17:$BZ$17=$D6)*($C$18:$BZ$18=$E6), , )), IF($C$8:$BZ$8=$C6, IF($C$17:$BZ$17=$D6, IF($C$18:$BZ$18=$E6, $C$16:$BZ$16))), 0))
```

In order to provide some maths without errors, I've shifted the calculation ranges to C:BZ. Array formulas still need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.

By appropriately locking either the row, column or both of the cell addresses, we can use the column header to identify a different category from column B as I have done with DATA LINE. The formula can be simply filled right.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It works but this formula assumes all the dates are in ascending order. Is it possible to allow for a random order?

Comment: @TheHoff - it will add several dozen characters to the formula but the maximum date can be sought on an exact match.

Comment: I'm sorry, I've tried to come up with a solution for that, but it's just not working. Can you please tell me how to adapt the formula?

Comment: @TheHoff - I edited the answer above to include your request a short time ago.